# How can I use custom Spinner class in spinner object to fire OnItemSelectedListener event every-time

Tags: java, android, listener, android-spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I have a OnItemSelectedListener for my Spinner, but it is not called when the selected item is the same as the previous one.I also implemented OnClickListener but it doesn't worked. I have found some solution. But I don't know how can I use it. I need to catch every-time a user click on an item.

JAVA CODE:

```
spn_filter_category.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(position),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

XML CODE:

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spn_filter_category"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: `it is not called when the selected item is the same as the previous one` what does it mean exactly.

Comment: I want to use custom Spinner class to do that. How can I implement this? @meda

Answer (score 0):

If you select an different item `onItemSelected` gets called.

If you don't select a different one it means you have not selected an item, then `onNothingSelected` gets called.

```
 spn_filter_category.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(position),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

             CharSequence message = "called when the selected item is the same as the previous one";  
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```